# Anyone know why my webpage that uses jquery doesn't format correctly in IE?

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-9

I have been working on creating a website for a professor at my college to help teach basic php.  I have been designing it and using Firefox to preview it and didn't really think to test it in IE till now and I discovered that it does not preview correctly.  The jQuery navigation loads vertically when it should load horizontal.  I used the W3C validator to check my code in my homepage and my css sheet and they both check out.  I have read that IE has to have a correct DocType in order to load pages sometimes which I assume mine is correct.  I am using a jquery menu for my navigation bar and a jquery accordion in my body.  Any ideas why they are being displayed incorrectly and why they are not being centered in the middle of the page?

[image: IE screenshot showing broken formatting]

I would like it to be viewable in IE 9 and any newer versions.  So to be specific does anyone have any ideas why this page won't load correctly in IE 9.

Here is the link: http://cite.nwmissouri.edu/projects/php/

Here is the current code of the homepage:

```
<!-- Author: Drew Scott-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
<link href="css/external.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jMenu.jquery.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" media="screen" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/accordion.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jMenu.jquery.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>PHP Practice</title>

<style type="text/css">

body {
   height:100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background-size: 100%;
   background-attachment: inherit;
   background-color:#d1d1d4;
}    
</style>    
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">

<div id="header">
  </div>
  <div id="navigation">

  <ul id="jMenu">
    <li>
    <a href="index.html" style="text-decoration: none" class="fNiv">Home</a>
    </li>
            <li>
                <a class="fNiv">The Basics</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="arrow"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="basics.html" style="text-decoration: none">Basics</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>Category 2.8</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a>Category 2.3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>Category 2.7</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a>Category 2.3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
      </li>


            <li>
                <a class="fNiv">Installation</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="arrow"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="installApache.html" style="text-decoration: none">Apache</a>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="installPHP.html" style="text-decoration: none">PHP</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="fNiv">HTML</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="arrow"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="xhtml.html" style="text-decoration: none">Basics</a>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>Other</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="fNiv">Examples</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="arrow"></li>
                    <li><a>Basic PHP</a></li>
                    <li><a>Downloading</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a>Other</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a>Category 4.3</a></li>
                            <li><a>Category 4.3</a></li>
                            <li><a>Category 4.3</a></li>
                            <li><a>Category 4.3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="fNiv">MYSQL</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="arrow"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a>MYSQL</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a>Category 5.3</a></li>
                            <li><a>Category 5.3</a></li>
                            <li><a>Category 5.3</a></li>
                            <li><a>Category 5.3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a>Category 5.2</a></li>
                    <li><a>Category 5.2</a></li>
                    <li><a>Category 5.2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a class="fNiv">PHP</a></li>

            <li>
                <a class="fNiv">Help</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="arrow"></li>
                    <li><a>Category 7.2</a></li>
                    <li><a>Category 7.2</a></li>
                    <li><a>Category 7.2</a></li>
                    <li><a>Category 7.2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
    </ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#jMenu").jMenu();
            });
        </script>

        </div>
  <div id="main">
<div id="editable">

            <div id="information">
            <div id='accordion_example'>
              <h2>What is PHP</h2>
              <p>PHP (recursive acronym for PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor) is a widely-used open source general-purpose scripting language that is especially suited for web development and can be embedded into HTML. </p>

              <h2>The Basics</h2>
              <p>PHP scripting starts with &lt;?php and ends with ?> <br />
              &lt;?php
              <br />
              <br />
              ? > <br /> 
              Can be placed anywhere in the document <br />
              Can have multiple PHP tags in a document <br />
              PHP file contains HTML tags and PHP scripting code <br />
              </p>

              <h2>XHTML</h2>
              <p>Stands for eXtensible Hypertext Markup Language<br /> <br />
              Markup in this name refers to the coded tags that allow the web page designer to format documents displayed on the web <br /><br />
              Tool for designing the format of a web page <br />
              </p>

              <h2>Resources</h2>
              <p> Some web pages you may want to look at for reference are: <br />
                  www.w3schools.com <br />
                  www.stackoverflow.com <br />
                  www.php.net <br />

              </p>

              <h2>Examples</h2>
              <p> examples </p>

              <h2>MYSQL</h2>
              <p> sql </p>

            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the CSS as well:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#container{
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    border-top: black thin solid;
    border-right: black thin solid;
    border-bottom: black thin solid;
    border-left: black thin solid;

    background-color: #575757;
}

#header{
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url(../images/header2.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 125px;
    position: center;
}

#navigation{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height:40px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #322f32;
    position: center;
    /*
    border-top: #99989d thin solid;
    border-bottom: #99989d thin solid;
    */
    border-bottom: black thin solid;
    border-top: black thin solid;
}

#main {
width:730px;
height:auto;
position:relative;
top:20px;
left:30px;
bottom:20px;
right:30px;

padding-left:3px;
padding-right:3px;
padding-bottom:3px;
padding-top:3px;

background-color:#d1d1d4;
}

#information{
    padding: 2px;

;}

#editable{
    padding: 1px;
}
```

Comment: What version of IE? and, no it isn't acceptable to provide a link to your website if that is the only means of us seeing what's actually not working.

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: If I remember correctly, you cannot have any element before your doctype (not even a comment) or IE will switch to quirksmode... so remove your comment above the doctype and see if that will fix the issue.

Comment: To help narrow this down, please check what rendering mode IE is using. Press F12 and open the developer console in IE and look at what it says in the menu bar for Browser Mode and Document Mode.

Comment: Removing the code above the Doc Type fixed my problem, which is weird because I am pretty sure I tried this before and it didn't change anything but it works great now, thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it seems that my comment above fixed it, I will add it as an answer:

You cannot have any element before your doctype (not even a comment) or IE will switch to quirksmode... so remove your comment above the doctype and see if that will fix the issue.